# add 15 days to every date in a pandas DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a pandas DateTimeIndex.  I want to add fifteen days to every date.

```
import pandas as pd    

tidx = pd.date_range(end='2016-04-30', freq='M', periods=2)

tidx

DatetimeIndex(['2016-03-31', '2016-04-30'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

I want:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-04-15', '2016-05-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

I've done:

```
pd.to_datetime([pd.datetime(t.year, t.month + 1, 15) for t in tidx])
```

This breaks as soon as `t.month + 1` is greater than 12.  Is there a generally accepted good way to do date math across an entire series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use `offsets`, see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#using-offsets-with-series-datetimeindex):

```
print (tidx + pd.offsets.Day(15))
DatetimeIndex(['2016-04-15', '2016-05-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Answer (score 3):

alternatively you can use [Timedelta()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html):

```
In [49]: tidx + pd.Timedelta('15d')
Out[49]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-04-15', '2016-05-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

In [50]: tidx + pd.Timedelta(days=15)
Out[50]: DatetimeIndex(['2016-04-15', '2016-05-15'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```